# How to insert image in word document header

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, dynamics-crm-2011

How to insert image in header of word document. I have written a plugin for renaming while attaching a document in an entity. How to insert a logo in header of word document before saving the file. The code in c# will also help me.

Comment: @Andrew Barber - why it has been closed? Please reopen it. I am facing the same problem and got another solution which is unavailable in the below answers. Request you to reopen it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Document doc = new Document();
  doc.LoadFromFile(@"E:\JaneEyre.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
 HeaderFooter header = doc.Sections[0].HeadersFooters.Header;
  header.Paragraphs[0].Text = "Preview";
  Image logo = Image.FromFile(@"D:\E-ICEBLUE.png");
  header.Paragraphs[0].AppendPicture(logo).TextWrappingStyle = TextWrappingStyle.Tight;
  HeaderFooter footer = doc.Sections[0].HeadersFooters.Footer;
  doc.SaveToFile("Sample.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Sample.docx");footer.Paragraphs[0].Text = "Author: Charlotte Brontë";
```

Comment: Hello Hassan, i have used this only but its giving me evaluation copy message on header and when i try to open file its telling me that file is corrupted. I have used spire.DOC dll only

Comment: are you sure that your spire.doc dll works with your word version?

Comment: yes. Its giving warning when i try to open file after attaching that , file is corrupted click yes to open file. If i open the file then image will be be attached.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code to insert image in header of word document:

```
 foreach (wd.Section section in CurrentDocument.Sections)
 {
  word.HeaderFooter header= section.Headers[wd.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
  wd.Shape oshape = header.Shapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\mahammadi\Desktop\icon\plus2.png",  left, top, width, height);
 }
```